# Regular expression to get consecutive numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following regular expression,

```
[M][1-4][-][Q][1-4]{1}['][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}
```

In this, `[0-9]{2}` and `[0-9]{2}` at the end must be consecutive numbers. i.e; `09-10` or `11-12` or `12-13` etc

Can any one please help me how i can change the expression to get the required format

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this job: regex has no notion of numerical values of one or more digits. I recommend you simply match this as you're doing it now, and then with check with "normal" programming if the two numbers are consecutive.

Comment: For fun: http://ideone.com/do403

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that since it depends too heavily on the context.

In fact, you can do that but you'll have to manually insert each combination in the regexp. Which is not something a sane man would do. And it's not scalable or readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare numerical values using RegExps....

Regex is great at syntax, but rubbish at semantics. So regex will definitely help you recognise x-y but you're asking too much to then move on to reason about the relationship between x and y.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this

```
M[1-4]-Q[1-4][']([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})
```

1. You don't need some of your square brackets.
2. You should not do this directly in regex. I put brackets around those numbers, that means you can find the first number in capture group 1 and the second in capture group 2.
   Now I would convert those two variables into numbers, subtract them and check if the difference is 1.

Comment: <picky>With a special case for 99-00</picky> :-)